# Seeing empty log file after logging

Tags: python, logging

I want to create a log file in Python 3.6 & save the time for different operations.

So I used this code:

```
def create_logger(logFile, fileLogLevel, streamLogLevel):
    # create logger for "Sample App"
    logger = logging.getLogger('Seller Explosion')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create file handler which logs WARNING messages
    fh = logging.FileHandler(logFile, mode='w')
    fh.setLevel(fileLogLevel)

    # create console handler with a higher log level
    ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    ch.setLevel(streamLogLevel)

    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)8s --- %(message)s ' +
                                  '(%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    return logger
```

While executing the code I'm using following command

```
logger = create_logger('<path to my folder>/TimeLog.log', logging.WARNING, logging.WARNING)
startTime=time.ctime()
logTime="Start Time for uploading: "+startTime
logger.info(logTime)
```

But while going to my path, I'm seeing that `TimeLog.log` is a blank file with size 0 byte. Can you please suggest me what error I'm making?

Answer (score 1):

You set your handlers to filter on the `WARNING` level:

```
logger = create_logger(..., logging.WARNING, logging.WARNING)
```

and

```
fh.setLevel(fileLogLevel)
# ...
ch.setLevel(streamLogLevel)
```

then logged an `INFO` level message. `INFO` is a *lower*, *less severe* level from `WARNING`, so is filtered out by the handler.

You need to log at `WARNING` level or higher (so `WARNING`, `ERROR` or `CRITICAL`, or a numeric value of 30 and up), *or* configure your handlers to handle lower levels (so `INFO`, `DEBUG`, or `NOTSET`, or a numeric value of 20 or below).

For example, `logger.warn(logTime)` causes data to be added to your log file. And if you used `logging.INFO` for the second argument to `create_logger()`, the `logger.info()` call would also have the same effect.

From the [`Handler.setLevel()` method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setLevel):

> Sets the threshold for this handler to level. **Logging messages which are less severe than level will be ignored**. When a handler is created, the level is set to `NOTSET` (which causes all messages to be processed.

Bold emphasis mine; also see the [*Logging levels* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels) for their ordering and numeric values.

Note that creating a log message with a timestamp *in the log message* is rather redundant, as your log format already includes a timestamp:

```
>>> startTime = time.ctime()
>>> logTime = "Start Time for uploading: " + startTime
>>> logger.warn(logTime)
[2018-01-17 16:36:20]  WARNING --- Start Time for uploading: Wed Jan 17 16:36:20 2018 (<stdin>:1)
```